# Как сделать указатель на двумерный массив указателей в c++?

Tags: c++, массивы

Допустим у меня есть массив указателей:

```
int *arr[8][8];
```

Как мне объявить указатель на этот массив?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Указатель на целый массив вот так: `int *(*ptr)[8][8];`. Здесь тот же принцип, что и в приоритетах операторов: сначала применяются штуки справа от имени, а потом слева; если это не изменяется скобками.

```
       ptr          // ptr - это
      *ptr          // указатель на
     (*ptr)         // ...
     (*ptr)[8]      // массив из 8
     (*ptr)[8][8]   // массивов из 8
    *(*ptr)[8][8]   // указателей на
int *(*ptr)[8][8]   // int
```

Если нужен указатель на один элемент массива (один подмассив), а не на весь, то убрать одну `[8]`.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @RomanKholod Главное - никогда так не делайте.

Answer (score 1):

```
using t_MyArray = int * [8][8];

t_MyArray arr;
t_MyArray * p_arr;
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну раз уже два варианта есть... Бог любит Троицу :)

```
typedef int* array[8][8];
array * ptr;
```

Кстати, в помощь см. [тут](https://cdecl.org/?q=int*%20%28*arrptr%29%5B8%5D%5B8%5D).